Heredero del mejor "hacer" culinario
¿Es correcto decir "heredero del mejor hacer culinario" en "el Mesón-Restaurante "EL CORDERO", heredero del mejor hacer culinario"? O sea, ¿se usa "hacer" como sustantivo en este caso?
Además, ¿por qué no simplemente decir “el mejor cocinero”, refiriendo al restaurante, y ya está. Me parece que “el mejor hacer culinario” es algo verboso. Bueno, ¿quizás esto sea mi preferencia personal?
Y si sigo su estructura, ¿pordría yo describir a estudiante con muy buenas notas “el chico es ”el mejor hacer estudioso”? ¡Muchas gracias!


Gracias por su comentario. El enlace que me ha aportado solo ha resuelto una de mis dudas. Mi otra duda es, ¿por qué no simplemente decir “el mejor cocinero”, refiriendo al restaurante, y ya está. Me parece que “el mejor hacer culinario” es algo verboso. Bueno, ¿quizás esto sea mi preferencia personal?

"El hacer culinario" no es lo mismo que "el mejor cocinero": Lo primero hace referencia a una habilidad, mientras que lo otro se refiere a una persona.

A la primera pregunta de si es correcto el uso de mejor hacer culinario, la respuesta es que si, porque corresponde a un proceso que se llama "sustantivación sintáctica".
El infinitivo de los verbos tiene valor de sustantivo, y así se puede decir de alguien que su "(decir/cantar/jugar/correr/hacer/pensar [etc]" es el mejor  *(o bien ,  correcto, pobre, deficitario, excelso ** [o cualquier adjetivo que lo califique y pondere]"
En cuanto a la segunda pregunta, no. La forma por la que averiguas no sigue el mismo patrón gramatical. El "mejor hacer culinario" es una referencia aplicada a la actividad del restaurante, no una calificación del cocinero; por lo que tu "intentar" extrapolar esa fórmula a una persona (estudiante) no funciona. En todo caso aplicaría   decir algo destacando su buen hacer estudiantil

Claro que es correcto, en ese contexto "hacer" da a entender sobre el arte de la cocina por lo que es totalmente valido.

El sustantivo “hacer” refiere en este caso a la cocina. El restaurante ha heredado la mejor manera de cocinar. Este es un uso correcto.
